# How can you prevent SwiftUI clipShape from affecting sub-views

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a view that uses the `clipShape` modifier to clip its contents to a specific shape. I also have a button as a deeply nested descendant of this view. The `clipShape` modifier on the higher-level view affects the button. How can I clip the top-level view without affecting sub-views?

As a minimal example, the following view exhibits this behaviour. The background of the button is clipped so it does not fully fill the shape. Removing the `clipShape` modifier on the stack resolves the issue. See the attached simulator screenshot for the effect this has.

```
VStack {
  Button(action: {}) { Text("Button") }
    .padding(20)
    .background(Color.orange)
    .cornerRadius(50)
    .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 50).stroke())
}
.clipShape(Capsule())
```

I have tried placing the `clipShape` modifier on different views (such as `Color.clear`) instead of a stack, but that doesn't seem to make any difference.

[image: Simulator screenshot]

Comment: This was a bug. Works fine with Xcode 12.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works correctly with Xcode 12b

Here is a workaround for Xcode 11.x

```
VStack {
  Button(action: { print(">> works")}) { Text("Button") }
    .padding(20)
    .background(Color.orange)
    .cornerRadius(50)
    .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 50).stroke())
}
.compositingGroup()       // << here
.clipShape(Capsule())
```

Comment: this solved nested clipping padding issues. Thanks.